Washing machine drain pipe blowbag
I basically have the same problem with the opposite situation to Washing machine drain pipe backing up
I had a newer washing machine that never backed up, but like most new things it was engineered to require $150 replacement part when the agitator went out so we bought an older one. Our house was built in the 1970s and we have a 2" waste pipe (at least that's what this looks like to me).
We bought an older washer that actually fills up the waste pipe when draining. No results with a 25' snake, blow bag, looking down the roof vent, lye, or drain cleaning foam, but dumping a half gallon of sulphuric acid and rinsing with hot water seemed to sort things for a while. About 6 months later and it seems like it's built up soap/hair again maybe?
Honestly what I would love is to be able to use the washer as a blowbag. Our water hose doesn't produce enough volume to fill up the pipe and push anything through, but the washing machine clearly produces enough volume - and either it will also have enough pressure to force any partial block out, or I guess just not drain quite as fast.
Are there any products that work like a blowbag that I can add to the end of my washer drain hose, or am I stuck just trying to find a narrower washing machine drain hose?


Did you mean "blowback"?

What is a "blowbag"? That is a very uncommon term.

blowbag/blow bag/plumbers bladder - it's a rubber bladder with (typically) a garden hose attachment on one end and a small hole in the other. When the water pressure fills up it expands and forms a seal around the pipe. Whatever your water pressure is (10psi?) is what it will press against your blockage with, typically forcing it down the drain

The blockage is not likely due to loose accumulations that can be dealt with by something like a "blowbag". You are not going to "blow" intruding roots out of a drain. I've never witnessed a laundry drain with any significant blockage due to stuff being emitted by the clothes washer itself.

@kreemoweet You may also not have ever had a household with several dogs and human children... I don't think it's a matter of root intrusion (though it could be!) as pouring a half gallon of sulfuric acid down the drain clears the blockage for a month or two. I don't think the roots would grow fast enough for that, and we didn't have any issues until we changed to an entirely different washer.

Reduce the flow rate from washing machine
Your faucet and hose has a flow rate of 1.5 GPM and the drain has no problem with that.
You washing machine pump tries to pump out 20 gallons in less than 5 minutes = 4 GPM, resulting in much higher flow rate that overwhelms the drain
Simple DIY experiment is to reduce the flow of the washing machine by inserting a reducer or simply using small hose.
You have 2 inch drain, so try with 3/4 inch hose reducer
If your washing machine drain is time based you might have some water left in the drum, in that case increase the flow restriction to 1 inch hose
If it is a model with water level sensor, the pump will continue running till the sensor triggers.

This is the preferred solution!


it seems like it's built up soap/hair again maybe

That's the real issue. Either you are clearing out the pipes well and they clog up quickly or you are never quite clearing them totally.
The key to making sure they don't clog quickly is to prevent stuff from going down the drain that shouldn't. The three most common things that come to mind are:

Washing machine lint. That is easy to prevent. Put a lint trap such as this example from Amazon - which I have used myself - on the end of the washing machine hose. Replace when it clogs up with lint.


Hair. That's tough. Hair in clothes will get trapped by the lint trap. Hair in bathtubs/showers is a lot tougher to catch. But if that is a significant part of the problem then an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure. There are many varieties but basically they are all some variant on cup with wide brim and tiny holes that sits in the drain and catches hair. With disgusting periodic cleaning needed, but a lot easier than dealing with the house drain clog.

Kitchen sink. Some scraps are OK. Some grease is OK. But keep it to a minimum - e.g., scrape plates into the trash before washing. When you do run stuff down the disposal, run a lot of water so that things wash away instead of getting stuck.


It is the combination of sticky stuff (grease) plus solid stuff (hair, lint) that results in tough clogs. Chemicals work well on some of it, but not all of it. Physical methods (snaking, air pressure) work but are not always easy.
As far as "blow bag", that is a bit confusing to me (and I think to others). But what I suspect you may be referring to is using pressure to force the bad stuff out of the drain. What I have found works well, at least some of the time, is using a large shop vac to blow into the main drain. The catch is that it is most effective when there are no paths for air to go backwards instead of forwards. In my case that works well as there is a removable section of pipe that I can block so that the air pressure is going only forwards through the main sewer pipe. But not everyone has that option.

A blow bag is the term I've always heard them called, basically when water flows through them they expand and block the pipe. That would be ideal for my scenario - I literally only need maybe 3 or 4 seconds before the drain empties enough - if it were 5' tall rather than 3 ish it wouldn't be an issue.
